# How to paste data into a specific row based on cell value?

Tags: vba, excel-365

I have a database worksheet. Every month we receive multiple plannings from factories, which I paste into a workbook from where I do analyses. But I want to automate.

For your reference I pasted an (adjusted) snippet of the workbook below:

[![workbook][1]][1]

In column B the month of data entry is listed.
The line below works to filter on the current month:

```
Worksheets("Production Plan Input").Range("A1:BQ290").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

But now I want to match the product group in column C of the filtered range to the workbooks with the different plannings.

For this, I need to copy range B3:Y3 from Workbook "Product type 1" worksheet "Monthly Plan" into workbook "Production Plan Analysis", worksheet "Plan Input", column AD:BA, but the row depends on the product type.

```
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production Plan Input")

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = "exe" Then
    ws.Range("AD" & i & ":BA" & i).Value = Paste
    End If
```

I get the error message "Compile Error: for without Next"

Comment: If that picture contains data then put it in your post - no-one is going to sit and type out your example from a picture.
To get rid of the compile error put `Next` at the end of your code snippet
Don't use cut & paste, just assign the cell value - but it's not clear from your code snippet where you got `Paste` from

Comment: You might be better off researching Power Query to get this data in the form you want

Comment: Excel which? 2016 or 365?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I fixed 2 errors in your code, and now it is running. But I'm not sure about exactly what you are needing. I suggest that you draft a before and after sheet results that you need.

Comment: @CHill60 Sorry about the picture! I was trying to show the data structure, so it hadn't occurred to me that pasting the data would be useful.

Comment: @SolarMike It's 365, I'll remove the other tag (thought I'd done that already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error:

[image]

After got rid of the compile time error, there is another error, now a runtime error, because you are not setting `ws` variable.
Just correct your piece of code:

```
 Public Sub Test()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production Plan Input")
    '^^^^ Another error that you would catch after pass the missing Next error
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "C").Value = "exe" Then
            ws.Range("AD" & i & ":BA" & i).Value = Paste
        End If
    Next ' <= here what is missing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

[image: Output]

```
Sub test()
    Dim exlapp As New Excel.Application, wb2 As Excel.Workbook, wb2ws As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, row As Long, d As Date, wb2Path As String, wb2wsName As String, copyRngStr As String, pasteToCol As String, dateCol As String, prodCol As String, prodType As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production Plan Input"): dateCol = "B": prodCol = "C"
    d = Date 'Today's date or use d = DateSerial(2023, 11, 1) if you want to run it retroactively
    prodType = "Product 1"
    wb2Path = "C:\Product type 1.xlsx" 'Edit the path to match where your Product type 1.xlsx is located. So maybe it's "C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\Product type 1.xlsx"
    wb2wsName = "Monthly Plan"
    copyRngStr = "B3:Y3"
    pasteToCol = "AD"
    
    Set wb2 = exlapp.Workbooks.Add(wb2Path)
    Set wb2ws = wb2.Sheets(wb2wsName)
    Debug.Print "Inside workbook: " & wb2Path & ", sheet: " & wb2ws.Name
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, prodCol).End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To lastRow
        If Year(d) = Year(ws.Cells(row, dateCol)) And month(d) = month(ws.Cells(row, dateCol)) Then
            If ws.Cells(row, prodCol) = prodType Then
                wb2ws.Range(copyRngStr).Copy
                ws.Range(pasteToCol & row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & DateSerial(Year(d), month(d), 1), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & DateSerial(Year(d), month(d) + 1, 1), Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
    
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False: Set wb2 = Nothing
    exlapp.Quit: Set exlapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here's what it seems you're trying to do:

First you manually add factories' future production plans into the current workbook ("Production Plan Analysis", worksheet "Production Plan Input"); Column B is the month/year of the plans; Column C is a list of different product types.

Then you want to copy the range "B3:Y3" from another workbook ("Product type 1", worksheet "Monthly Plan") into the current one ("Production Plan Analysis", worksheet "Production Plan Input") at column "AD" based on the month/year and product type and have everything sorted by current month/year in the current workbook, right?

You could also get data from workbooks for other product types using the approach you chose - I tried to put all the strings in one place for easier editing should you choose to go that route.

Also, there is a good suggestion in the comments for an alternative approach to accomplish your task. Hope this helps.